# Identify this Chopin snippet from Yale's 'Listening to Music' course

Tags: identify-this-song, piano, chopin

I'm taking the online 'Listening to Music' course by Professor Craig Wright from Yale University.
I was hoping you could help me identify where the Chopin snippet he played as an exercise at the time stamp 41:45 in Lecture 3 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t4echOq29d0&list=PLh9mgdi4rNezhx8YiGIV8I22ICSuzslja&index=3

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The extract is from the third movement of Frédéric Chopin's Piano Sonata No.2 B-flat minor, Op.35. 
[image] The sonata was published in 1840, but Chopin had composed this movement at least two years earlier. This movement is also known as his funeral march, in fact it was played at his own funeral (against his wishes). The first part of the movement is [better known](https://youtu.be/7-9wXQpzESo). This theme doesn't start until well over two minutes into the piece.